# Making Periodic URL Requests from an Activity

Tags: android

I have an activity which makes periodic requests (once every 15 seconds to get a json data feed).  The requests I am passing off to a AsyncTask so its not on the main UI thread.  So far so good.  But lets say that I request the feed and it takes 20 seconds to respond.  I really don't want to kick off another thread until say 30 seconds are up.  So ....

Is there a way to prevent the AsyncTask from running if there first one has not yet finished?

Also is there a way to timebox the AsyncTask to take no more than 30 seconds? reguardless of the Http timeout?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Duplicated questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667064/create-a-timer-to-send-http-request-periodically-android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045300/doing-http-request-from-android-using-timer

Personally, I'd propose to use `Handler` and link it to itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mutex variable to enforce this. Say, We call the variable `update`. This will be a boolean variable with initial value `true`.

Before running an Async task, Check the value of `update`, If it is `true` run the async task and set `update` to `false`.

After the end of the async task, in the `onPostExecute()` method, set `update` to `true` again.

So another async task will not be launched while one hasn't finished, thus ensuring exclusivity.